# split() is throwing an exception in production but not development. Why?

Tags: php

[`split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php) is throwing an exception in production (`exception 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'Function split() is deprecated' in /app/controllers/NegativeKeywordController.php:128`) but not development. How can I turn on exceptions in development?

Comment: Check the versions of PHP (phpInfo())? For error reporting see: [How do I get PHP Errors to display?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change `error_reporting` to `E_ALL` and restart Apache.

```
;error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT # old
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

Comment: That means your development is hiding more errors than the production.  This is not good practice as you have just experienced.  Please try to align them (or better yet, always enable all on errors on the dev.)